# Get Current Sitecore Role in Backend

Tags: server-role

How can I get the current Sitecore Role in my c# code like `Standalone`, `ContentManagement` or `ContentDelivery`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get Sitecore role using this

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["role:define"]
```

This value is stored in `appSettings` of `Web.config`

```
 <add key="role:define" value="Standalone" />
```